# org-agenda-colums deadline time style

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'm using org-mode with `C-c C-x C-c` `(org-agenda-columns)` like a organizer, the format which I use for that

```
(setq org-columns-default-format
      "%TODO %30ITEM %30DEADLINE %15SCHEDULED %3PRIORITY %TAGS %5Effort(Effort){:} %6CLOCKSUM")
```

As you see in **DEADLINE** column, all dates format are `DD.MM.YYYY` It's not easy to understand how many days that we have for due date.

[image: agenda view]

Regular `org-agenda` `(C-a a)` shows to us what is the due date.

[image]

I want to learn how to change `DEADLINE` column like in `org-agenda` (In 2 days,10 d. ago)

**Maybe this links can help**

- [Use formula in agenda clockreport to convert time? (pomodoro count in Agenda)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12839/use-formula-in-agenda-clockreport-to-convert-time)
- [Org Agenda Special Properies](http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-properties.html#Special-properties)
- [Column Attributes](http://orgmode.org/manual/Column-attributes.html#Column-attributes)

Comment: I can see you put effort into this question, but I really don't understand the sentence between the two figures (the sentence that starts with *"But I want if..."*). Could you try to expand that sentence with more conent to make it more clear?

Comment: Sorry for that problem. I changed main part of question and pictures. I hope now its better. Thank you

Comment: This is not something that needs to be calculated, but rather extracted and displayed -- on any line that contains something like **in 2 days** or **10 d. ago** when not in columns view, evaluate:  `(text-properties-at (point))` and look at **extra**.  The default for evaluating an expression is to truncate the output, so either modify the `eval-expression-print-level` and `eval-expression-print-length` to `nil`, or create a message -- e.g., `(message "%s" (text-properties-at (point)))`.  This feature request undoubtedly involves modifying the source code.  I don't use columns view.

Comment: Columns view is just a bunch of overlays that cover up the regular org-agenda buffer that is underneath -- all of the original text properties are still present.

Comment: I see that **extra** line I'll try to write that codes. But first I have to learn how to use `eval-expression-print-level` and `eval-expression-print-length` thanks for help :)

Comment: I like to see everything in my message buffer when I evaluate an expression that throws a result, that way I don't have to wrap it in a `message` to see everything.  In my `.emacs` or `init.el` file, I use `(setq eval-expression-print-length nil)` and `(setq eval-expression-print-level nil)` so that there is no truncation.

Comment: Here is an example of how to extract the value you are seeking:  `(get-text-property (point) 'extra)`

Comment: Thank you for informations I read 2 days ago but. I realize I didn't answer to you about what I did. Nowadays **final** week so I have to work for them :))