# How to add a column in org-mode agenda clockreport to show percentage of time for each group of activities?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have been using Bernt Hansen's org-mode setup (http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html - modified slightly to my needs) for some time and I came up with a question that I cannot solve.

I would like to add a colunn to my clock table report showing the percentage of each group of activities. The attached is an example of a typical clock table report. I would like to add a column next to `Time` showing the percentage of time spent in nonValueAdded.org (i.e., 16.59=100*(1:13/7:20)), service.org, teaching.org.

After reading [Use formula in agenda clockreport to convert time? (pomodoro count in Agenda)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12839/use-formula-in-agenda-clockreport-to-convert-time), I tried adding `:formula "$4=(%CLOCKSUM/%CLOCKSUM_T)*(100);t"` as below

```
(setq org-agenda-clockreport-parameter-plist
  (quote (:link t :maxlevel 5 :fileskip0 t :compact t :narrow 80 :formula "$4=(%CLOCKSUM/%CLOCKSUM_T)*(100);t")))
```

but it was not successful.

I appreciate any help on this.

Best,

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formula is quite simple ;)

```
(setq org-agenda-clockreport-parameter-plist
      (quote (:link t :maxlevel 5 :fileskip0 t :compact t :narrow 80 :formula %)))
```

Comment: Thanks mutbuerger! It worked perfectly. Couldn't guess it would be that simple though :)